# how to initialize a vector struct of vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, structure

so I have this structure:

```
struct lang_accuracy{ 
    std::vector<int> sum;
    vector<string> language;
};
```

and this vector of type structure

```
vector<lang_accuracy> s;

...
for (int i = 0;...)
{
  s.push_back(lang_accuracy());
  for (int k = 0;...)
  {  
      s[i].sum.push_back(); // `<- error`
      s[i].sum[k]=`some integer value`;
  }
  s[i].language.push_back(); // `<- error`
  s[i].language[i] = `some string`;
}
```

So, since I have 2 vectors in my structure, I must first allocate more memory with `push_back` in `s` and than go on element `i` of vector `s` and initialize.
But `sum` and `language` are also vectors, and for some reason, I can't compile the above because I get this :

> error C2661: '`std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back`': no overloaded function takes 0 arguments

I know in the case of `vector<vector<type>>` you `push_back` elements in the first vector and when that is full, you `push_back` the whole vector into the other.
Here I can't do that, because `sum` and `lang` are not recognized as stand-alones outside the struct.

How should I populate my `sum` than?

Comment: The error is clear. You need to push something. Try `s[i].sum.push_back({});` instead. Or just `s[i].sum.push_back(some_integer_value);`

Comment: @DimChtz Why would you push_back {} and then assign when you can simply push_back the number itself? That seems silly to me but maybe I missed something.

Comment: @borgleader I think that was just to keep the uniform and general syntax in case OP used `language` instead of `sum`.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Again though, why push back a default object and assign when you can push back the thing youre going to assign. The type doesnt matter.

Comment: @Borgleader Yeah you're right, I'm unsure, don't shoot the messenger !

Comment: Should also be able to do something like `s.push_back(lang_accuracy{{numbers go here},{strings go here}});` in cases where you already know what's going in.

Comment: @SombreroChicken I'm not shooting, I'm asking questions. Shooting comes later ;)

Comment: Resistance is futile, huh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is quite clear. You're not providing anything to `push_back` to add to the vector.

For example, to add something to `sum` you should specify what you want to add in the first place:

```
s[i].sum.push_back(42); // add 42 to `sum`
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use `emplace_back` supplying value, this way no temporaries will be involved:

```
s.emplace_back();
for (int k = 0;...)
{  
    s[i].sum.emplace_back(42);
}
s[i].language.emplace_back("whatever");
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `vector<T>::push_back(T)` is not primarily for allocating memory, it is for adding an item to the back of the vector (and allocates more memory for that item if necessary).

Instead of your 2-step approach, you need only one:

```
s[i].sum.push_back(`some integer value`);
```